How to retrieve a WhatsApp message from the API using the message ID?
I'm working on a project where I need to retrieve WhatsApp messages from the API, specifically targeting messages that have been processed through WhatsApp's template. I have the message ID for these template-resolved messages, and I need to fetch the exact message content as it was sent to the end user.
Could someone provide guidance on how to accomplish this using the WhatsApp API? I've searched through the documentation but haven't found a clear method for fetching individual messages by their IDs. Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.
I was expecting to find a straightforward method or endpoint in the WhatsApp API documentation that would allow me to retrieve a message by its ID.
